# What does the lookup field contain

Tags: trigger, process-builder, lookup

When there is a lookup relation between 2 objects standard/custom the **lookup field on child object is intended to contain only a pointer to the ID of the parent and establish the association between the parent and the child**.
**Also this value cannot be changed**. But when i refer few examples i can see some lookup field to contain reference number and some contain name which when clicked on the child record page redirects to the parent record page.

- I need clarification on what value can and cannot be in the lookup field
- is there any possibility to change it via process builder/trigger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database stores the record Id. Most UI elements will instead display a link whose text is more user-friendly, such as the `Name`, `CaseNumber`, etc. Process Builder or Apex Trigger can both change which record you look up to, but there is no way to change which field is displayed in standard UI elements.

Comment: is there a possibility to modify what lookup field should display on UI?

Comment: Not for out of the box UI elements, no.